# Как поставить дочернюю категории на Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

есть сайт http://krakendev.webtm.ru/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

тут только можно поставить товары а не подразделы.

вот код header php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Было бы наверное проще, если бы использовалось `wp_nav_menu()` и у Вас не было бы такой проблемы. `query_posts()` -- это плохо, постарайтесь использовать `WP_Query`.

Comment: 1. Код должен быть кодом, а не картинкой. 2. Непонятна суть вопроса Исправь вопрос, внятно описав проблему.

Comment: хук для меню правильнее использовать, он сразу все вложенное вытащит. А твой код вытащит все категориий, а вложена она или нет, придется запрашивать для каждой, есть ли у нее родитель и кто родитель, затем рекурсией формировать дерево, это все уже есть готовое, хватит велосипедить!